# How to create exposed filter programmatically?

Tags: views, 8

I try to make my own exposed filtrer for a particular views, but I have alway an error when I try to add my new filter in my view:

> Notice : Undefined index: original_configuration dans
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\Broken->buildOptionsForm()

[image: error message]

**File :** modules/custom/MY_MODULE/src/Plugin/views/filter/SessionsFilter.php

```
  namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\views\filter;

  use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
  use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\FilterPluginBase;
  use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
  use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
  use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
  use Drupal\views\Views;

   /**
    * Filtre custom des session N & N-1
    *
    * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
    *
    * @ViewsFilter("custom_sessions_annee_filter")
    */
    class SessionsFilter extends FilterPluginBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
      parent::init($view, $display, $options);
      $this->valueTitle = t('Filtre Sessions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function defineOptions() {
      $options = parent::defineOptions();

      $options['session_annee']['default'] = [];

      return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Provide the basic form which calls through to subforms.
     * If overridden, it is best to call through to the parent,
     * or to at least make sure all of the functions in this form
     * are called.
     */
    public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);
      $sessions = [
        0 => 2017,
        1 => 2018,
      ];

      if (!empty($sessions)) {
        $form['session_annee'] = [
          '#type'          => 'checkbox',
          '#title'         => $this->t('Filtre par années'),
          '#options'       => $sessions,
          '#default_value' => $this->options['session_annee'],
          '#description'   => $this->t('Liste des années'),
        ];
      }
      else {
        $form['fields'] = [
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => [],
        ];
      }
      if (isset($form['expose'])) {
        $form['expose']['#weight'] = -5;
      }
    }

    /**
     * @param                    $form
     * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
     */
    protected function valueForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $sessions = [];

      $form['value']  = [];
      // We use additional selector on exposed forms.
      if ($this->options['exposed']) {
        $langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();

        //récupérer les dernières sessions
        $sessions = _my_module_get_last_session();

        $form['session_annee'] = [
          '#type' => 'radio',
          '#title' => t('Sessions'),
          '#options' => $sessions,
          '#default_value' => 0,
          '#attributes' => [
            'class' => ['session-exposed'],
          ],
        ];
      }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateExposed(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      // Only validate exposed input.
      if (empty($this->options['exposed']) || empty($this->options['expose']['identifier'])) {
        return;
      }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function exposedTranslate(&$form, $type) {
      parent::exposedTranslate($form, $type);

      // We use custom validation for "required", so don't want the Form API to
      // interfere.
      // @see ::validateExposed()
      $form['#required'] = FALSE;
    }

    public function query() {

      $this->ensureMyTable();
//
//      $field_session = "{$this->tableAlias}.{$this->realField}_session";
//      //bundle  = partion | tarifs
//      //entity_id = nid partion | tarifs
//      //field_session_target_id = nid session
//      $field_annee = "{$this->tableAlias}.{$this->realField}_annee";
//      //bundle  = session
//      //entity_id = nid session
//      //field_annee_value = 0,1,2,3, ... index de correspondance dans le champs liste [ 0 => '2017', 1 => '2018'...

      $nid_session = 131;

      $configuration_session = [
        'table' => 'node__field_session',
        'field' => 'entity_id',
        'left_table' => 'node_field_data',
        'left_field' => 'nid',
        'type'       => 'LEFT',
        'operator' => '=',
        'extra' => [ // These are extra conditions views adds by default, I just copied them so it looks like any filter.
          0 =>[
            'field' => 'deleted',
            'value' => 0
          ],
          1 => [
            'left_field' => 'langcode',
            'field' => 'langcode'
          ]
        ]
      ];

      $join_session = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $configuration_session);
      $this->query->addRelationship('node__field_session', $join_session, 'node_field_data');

      $this->query->addWhere('AND', 'node__field_session.bundle', 'parution', '=');
      $this->query->addWhere('AND', 'node__field_session.field_session_target_id', $nid_session, '='); // test : recup les contenu qui ont la session 2018
    }


    /**
     * Do some minor translation of the exposed input
     */
    public function acceptExposedInput($input) {
      if (empty($this->options['exposed'])) {
        return TRUE;
      }

      $rc = parent::acceptExposedInput($input);

      return $rc;
    }


    /**
     * Display the filter on the administrative summary
     */
    public function adminSummary() {
      return $this->operator;
    }
  }
```

**File :** my_module.module

```
  /**
   * @param $data
   */
  function sepm_views_data_alter(&$data)
  {
    $data['node']['my_view_name'] = [
        'title' => t('Filtre Session'),
        'filter' => [
            'title' => t('Annees'),
            'help' => 'Filtrer les contenus en fonctions des sessions',
            'field' => 'nid',
            'id' => 'custom_sessions_annee_filter',
        ]
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing your filter, saving the view, clearing cache, and then trying to add the filter fresh?  It looks like that error is coming from the views Broken filter which makes me think that the view is unable to find your filter class.

Comment: Broken.php is a placeholder, so probably the plugin manager couldn't find your plugin. Check the namespace and file path, `views` in lower case and /filter/ is missing in the path.

Comment: I fix my filepath between my namespace and folders `my_module/src/plugin/views/filter` and I try to remove, savre view, clear cache and try to add the filter in my view (I can see it on the criteria list), but the problem persist...

Comment: you can see it because you have listed it in views_data, but you need to check whether your plugin class is discovered, for example with Drupal Console: `drupal debug:plugin views.filter`